# Create Envelope Error on Live Environment - One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: docusignapi

Envelope creation was worked well on the sandbox environment. After I made the integrator key live, and used it with the live account, I am getting the error:

Error calling CreateEnvelope: {\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED\",\r\n  \"message\": \"One or both of Username and Password are invalid.

Any idea why this is not working on production?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use URL from the web app. If you are using Legacy Auth Header flow, then you need to check with your DocuSign account manager to know on which site (DataCenter) your DocuSign account is in? Currently DocuSign accounts get created in one of the fours sites, NA1 (www)/NA2/NA3/EU(only for European customers).

To get the baseURL you need to make call to `GET /v2/login_information`,
which is like `https://{0}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`, where {0} will be the site on which your account is present.

If your account is in NA1(www), then you should call,

```
https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
```

If your account is in NA2, then you should call,

```
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
```

If your account is in NA3, then you should call,

```
https://na3.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
```

If your account is in EU, then you should call,

```
https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
```

Each account has a baseUrl property, returned in the response. Use this baseUrl in all future API calls as the base of the request URL.

Nowadays, per https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html DocuSign does not recommend using Legacy Auth Header, instead you should use new OAUTH flows which uses DocuSign Account Server instead of knowing and hitting a specific site.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anybody who has this question in future, please send an envelope manually from your docusign account and use the url of the envelope as your base path.

Comment: Which url you are referring to? You should use baseUrl from the API call.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on both of the answers that are already here (which I used to solve the issue).

Sign into your production docusign account and manually send out a contract. Once you receive the contract open up the contract from within the email and inspect the URL that is present.

As previously mentioned, it can be na3, na2, www, or eu. Change your base url to match. i.e. if you see https://na3.docusign.net/Signing/?ti=sometoken, you'll want to use:

https://na3.docusign.net/restapi as your base URL.